# Pyhtml - Print the order in the order in which it is run

Tags: automation, pytest

Have been working with pytest for sometime, (and really like it, I must say). I have been able to generate a self contained html with additional columns etc. What I need is either:

1. Have the results displayed in the order in which they are run (not Failed first as it normally appears in the self contained html output)
   OR
2. Print the order in which the tests are run. Am using @pytest.mark.run(order=123456) in my tests.

The order is important as there are dependency tests that needs to be executed in a certain sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure about pytest, but I worked with pyhtml and had a similar problem.

I would say you shuld use a "yield" operator in the function you are calling from your pyhtml part. If you are calling the pytest function direct from your pyhtml part, you shuld be able to write a new function, that calls pytest for you.